# No such file or directory

Tags: diff

I'm trying a command and when I enter it the first time it tells me:

```
diff: llet: No such file or directory
```

but then when I try it a second time, it works... Is there a reason why?

Here's the command: `rev tell > llet | diff tell llet | grep '^> ' | wc -l`

Comment: Did you create or move any files between the first and the second try? On the second try, did you recall the command from the shell history buffer, usually using the up-arrow key (guaranteeing that the command was absolutely the same as on the first try) or did you type it again manually (and might have unconsciously fixed a typo you did on the first time)? Use the `history` command to look at your past commands and make sure there is no difference between the tries: a single-letter difference would be enough to cause the error.

Comment: I did use the up arrow key to recall the same command which is why it's really weird haha. I didn't move anything in between, I just used the same command twice in a row and it worked. But thanks I'll keep looking!

Comment: Did you also intend to use two files `lett` and `llet` or were these suppose to be the same file?

Comment: woops typo its the same file thank you for noticing :')

Comment: The first `|` doesn't really make sense here - you're already redirecting the `rev` command's stdout so there's nothing to pipe - it should likely be `;` or `&&`. In particular, if you're relying on the redirection to *create* the `llet` file (I assume `lett` was a typo) then remember that most shells don't guarantee the execution order of piped commands - that's likely why it didn't exist the first time you ran the pipeline

Answer (score 3):

As written, the command doesn't make much sense (even fixing the typo).
You are creating `llet` by redirecting and in parallel, running diff which might start before the file is created and might use the file before rev is finished.

Instead, try one of these alternatives:

Create the file and then run diff instead of running diff in parallel:

```
rev tell > llet ; diff tell llet | grep '^> ' | wc -l
```

Don't save output from rev to a file, just send it to diff directly:

```
rev tell | diff tell - | grep '^> ' | wc -l
```

Save it to a file *and* to diff at the same time:

```
rev tell | tee llet | diff tell - | grep '^> ' | wc -l
```